# Lightning in Thunderbird is not usable

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I'm using Lightning 3.3.3 in Thunderbird 31.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.10. Because the Mozilla support sites seem little frustrating to me, I'm asking about it here.

But it seems that Lightning isn't working for me because of a major error. I don't know what the error is, but I can post two screenshots showing what it looks like:

[image]

and after changing the tab and switching back it looks like:

[image]

I already reinstalled it, but without change. It's not possible to work with it or create any new calendar (for example). What went wrong? It's really eating my nerves.

Comment: It seems strange to me that the latest installed version of Lightning in Thunderbird via automatic updating is 3.3.4 but the latest version of Lightning that is available to download from: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/ is version 3.3.3.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I downloaded and installed 3.3.4 manually from: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/calendar/lightning/nightly/3.3.4-candidates/build1/linux-x86_64/ because there weren't any updates on the 3.3.3. The errror/strange behaviour seems to be the same. But I found out, it's possible to create a new calendar by DOUBLE-CLICKING in the calendar area (even if File->New->Calendar doesn't work). I'll see whats possible else. Thanks karel.

Comment: No, it seems like I'm using an unfinished developer version (which is not the case). Making entries in the new calendar doesn't work, nearly all menus are deactivated and the calendar windows are missing.

Comment: I really need to find a solution for the problem. It hasn't changed so far. I find it strange, that obviously I'm the only person who experiences that.

Comment: After I posted my original comment, I checked my Lightning in Thunderbird to see if I could duplicate your problem, and Lightning was working properly. It occurs to me that it could be caused by another one of your T-bird extensions. Try uninstalling all of your T-bird extensions except for Lightning. Better yet, uninstall ALL of your T-bird extensions and then reinstall ONLY Lightning.

Comment: Okay, one thing I didn't try so far: Reinstall Thunderbird. I'll backup my profile folder (which I hope to be not involved in the problem) and reinstall it. It also could be a problem with the language in Thunderbird (I'm using German). --- I didn't see your edit, ok, I'll try it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but quite accidentally.

Removing all extensions and reinstall Lightning didn't help.
I tried to change the language of Thunderbird, which didn't help too.
I also installed version 3.3.4, no change.
Then I tried to import a calendar-file (.ics), it loaded but didn't show anything (that's how I expected it). **But then I reinstalled Lightning and the calendar shows up and is working.** I didn't expect that to be possible, due to a probable loss of all Lightning configuration, but somehow it worked.
[image]